# Удаление строки из файла под номером

Tags: php

Пытаюсь передать номер строки, которую нужно удалить. В итоге, ничего не получается и строка не удаляется. Справа стоят 777.

```
function DeleteLine($line) {
    $fopen=file($this->files);
    unset($fopen[$line]);
    $f=fopen($this->files, "w+");
    foreach($fopen as $string) { 
        fwrite($f, $string); 
    }
    fclose($f);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите что получилось в `$fopen`. Возможно, вы удаляете не ту стоку, которую хотите. А ещё я бы использовал `file_put_contents` потому что так короче. Ну и проверял бы возвращаемое значение на `false`

Answer (score 0):

Как уже все написали, код рабочий, проблема в чем-то другом. Плюс много лишнего кода, достаточно трёх строчек,

```
function DeleteLine($line) {
    $file = file($this->files);
    unset($file[$line]);
    file_put_contents($this->files, $file);
}
```

Но у этого подхода две проблемы.

Во-первых, расход ресурсов сервера, поскольку весь файл читается в память.
Во-вторых, в конкурентном окружении, каким является веб-сервер, при одновременных запросах рано или поздно из файла удалятся все строки до одной. Первый процесс обнулит файл чтобы записывать в него данные, второй прочитает этот пустой файл и потом его же запишет.

Поэтому лучше такой фигнёй не заниматься, а использовать базу данных, хотя бы sqlite.

Answer (score -1):

```
$strNum = 1;
$result = "";
$delLine = 2;
$fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp);
    if ($strNum != $delLine) $result .= $line;
    $strNum++;
}
fclose($fp);

$fw = fopen("test.txt", "w");
fwrite($fw, $result);
fclose($fw);
```

Еще вариант:

```
$file = preg_split("/\n/", file_get_contents("test.txt"));
unset($file[2]);
$fw = fopen("test.txt", "w");
foreach ($file as $str){
    fwrite($fw, $str."\n");
}
fclose($fw);
```

Answer (score -1):

Не большое замечание: так как в результате чтения файла, функция **file()** возвращает массив, элементы которого начинаются с нуля, то при попытке удаления первой строки **DeleteLine(1)** будет удалена вторая строка. В остальном же, код должен работать *(у меня на локалке он работает)* Посмотрите, что приходит в свойство **$this->files** - скорее всего только в этом и есть проблема.

Следующее, что не мешало бы подкорректировать, так это результат, возвращаемый функцией *(у вас результат всегда true, даже если ничего не было удалено)*. Ну и конечно, не помешает проверка на существование удаляемого элемента. С учётом этих замечаний код будет иметь такой вид:

```
var_dump(DeleteLine(2));
// Функция возвращает строку, которая была удалена, или false


function DeleteLine($line) {
    $delete_string = false;
    $lines = file($this->files, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    
    if (isset($lines[--$line])) {
        $delete_string = $lines[$line];
        unset($lines[$line]);
        
        $f = fopen($this->files, 'w+');
        foreach ($lines as $string) {
            fwrite($f, $string); 
        }
        fclose($f);
    }
    
    return $delete_string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ваша функция рабочая, но я бы добавил проверку на существование файла:

```
function DeleteLine($line){
    if (file_exists($this->files)){
        $fopen = file($this->files);
        unset($fopen[$line]);
        $f = fopen($this->files, "w+");
        foreach($fopen as $string) {
            fwrite($f, $string);
        }
        fclose($f);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Далее смотрите, что возвращается true или false. Если false, значит проблема с $this->files

Comment: Такая "проверка" называется "подавление ошибки",  а подавления ошибок быть не должно